# DateIntervalFormatter's dateTemplate not consistent with DateFormatter's dateFormat in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, dateformatter, dateinterval

I am trying to display a date interval formatted using a custom format. The format which I am using works well for a date but do not so good when used with a date interval.
I pus as comments what is displayed and what I expect. Is there truly a problem or my expectations are wrong, in case they are wrong, why so? also, how can I achieve the expected part?

```
import UIKit

let now = Date()
let tomorrow = now.addingTimeInterval(24.0 * 3600.0)
let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: now, end: tomorrow)

// Initialize Date Interval Formatter
let dateIntervalFormatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
dateIntervalFormatter.dateTemplate = "dd-MM-yyyy"

dateIntervalFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
dateIntervalFormatter.string(from: dateInterval)
// displays "12.–13.01.2022"
// expected "12-–13-01-2022"

dateIntervalFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
dateIntervalFormatter.string(from: dateInterval)
// displays "1/12/2022 – 1/13/2022"
// expected "12-01-2022 – 13-01-2022"

dateIntervalFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ro")
dateIntervalFormatter.string(from: dateInterval)
// displays "12.01.2022 – 13.01.2022"
// expected "12-01-2022 – 13-01-2022"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de")
let formatedTime = formatter.string(from: Date())
// displays "12-01-2022"
// expected "12-01-2022"
```

Comment: You are using a `template`, not a `format`, that's why. In the `DateFormatter` sample, if you used `formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddMMyyy")` instead of `formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"`formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy", you might see it. Also, a template doesn't need the "-", it won't translate them.

Comment: @Larme ok, I understand, so is there a way to achieve what I expected?

Comment: you should set the locale before setting the dateFormat

Comment: @LeoDabus for dateformatter it's working fine, no problem there, dateinterval is the problem, how can I make it to not ignore "-"

Comment: use a fixed locale "en_US_POSIX" if you don't want it localized

Comment: @LeoDabus I put as comments what I want, I want the expected comments

Comment: If you want it localized you should accept the format supplied by the formatter

Comment: Note that template is not the same as dateFormat

Comment: The order of the date components doesn't matter as well as the separator. You are supposed to only pass templates like yyyyMMdd

Answer (score 1):

A locale/template based format means "I yield the details to you", so the DateIntervalFormatter does what it pleases depending on the locale. The DateFormatter example, on the other hand, is not locale/template based, so you get what you specified in the format (not template) you supplied.

Comment: ok, I see, then how can I achieve what I expected?